# Using variables of single js scripts differently , while the script is loaded multiple times on page

Tags: javascript

I have a script named as view.js which does is counts the number of times a single div box is viewed on the page..... I have that mechanism well working when I load that script into only one div ...... but when I put that inside multiple divs inside single page it only works for the last script......
I know that js are loaded sequentially on a page ie only my last loaded scipt is suppose to work

can anyone tell me a way so that when I load my js multiple times inside different div they act as different scripts and run in parallel for count

and I also want to mention that the variable names will remain same for every script and I just want to use them differently for other scripts

also is there any solution using the js object...
please let me know of the solution

```
<div id="parentofad" >
    <div id="ad">
        <img src="gemma-correll-cool-beans-button-magnet-lg.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="adTagScript.js"></script>
</div>
<div id="parentofsecondad" >
    <div id="ad">
        <img src="gemma-correll-cool-beans-button-magnet-lg.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="adTagScript.js"></script>
</div>
```

**Edited**: jsfiddle snippet https://jsfiddle.net/1fxgwztk/

Comment: Could you please post the code snippet, it may help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now i guess you have a function that you call on page load for a specific class or id. What you must do is to initial that function for every class like this example

```
//Class
function Viewed(divID) { }

var div = new Viewed(divID);
```

Comment: <div id="parentofad" >
  <div id="ad">
   <img src="gemma-correll-cool-beans-button-magnet-lg.jpg" width="100" height="100">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="adTagScript.js"></script>
 </div>
 <div id="parentofsecondad" >
  <div id="ad">
   <img src="gemma-correll-cool-beans-button-magnet-lg.jpg" width="100" height="100">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="adTagScript.js"></script>

Comment: this is the sample code for file and script is src="adTagScript.js"  , now tell me how can I instantiate object for each time the script is loaded at the page

Comment: and I do not call any function I just load the script, so function has to be called on action on the scipt

Comment: create a jsfiddle or jsbin on your question for us to help you

Comment: here is the jsfiddle I have all the code but it may not work properly on jsfiddle because of the external files and links

Comment: I suggest you try to execute it on local machine and see if on scroll the state visible is printed for both the divs